# How to resolve "invalid operands of types" in an Arduino program?

Tags: c++, arduino

It's a manipulation of two codes.

First I send the latitude and longitude value found from the gps module by sms(arduino,gsm module), then by another code I send it to a php file in the server by using http protocol(arduino+gps/gsm/gprs shield). Now when I am merging two codes, it's showing errors like below:

```
Arduino: 1.8.10 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

    C:\Users\rafez\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\Hajji_Tracker\Hajji_Tracker.ino: In function 'void getGPSLocation()':

  Hajji_Tracker:58:29: error: invalid operands of types 'const char [12]' and 'char [16]' to binary 'operator+'

 Serial.println("Latitude  :"+latitude);

            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~

Hajji_Tracker:59:30: error: invalid operands of types 'const char [13]' and 'char [16]' to binary 'operator+'

 Serial.println("Longitude  :"+longitude);

            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~

C:\Users\rafez\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\Hajji_Tracker\Hajji_Tracker.ino: In function 'void sendTabData(String, int, boolean)':

Hajji_Tracker:91:18: error: incompatible types in assignment of 'String' to 'char [16]'

 latitude = data[3];

              ^

Hajji_Tracker:92:18: error: incompatible types in assignment of 'String' to 'char [16]'

 longitude =data[4];

              ^
```

```
C:\Users\rafez\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\Hajji_Tracker\Hajji_Tracker.ino:138:32: warning: invalid conversion from 'String*' to 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' [-fpermissive]

     serialSIM808.write(latitude);   // Add id to the url

                                ^

In file included from C:\Users\rafez\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\Hajji_Tracker\Hajji_Tracker.ino:1:0:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SoftwareSerial\src/SoftwareSerial.h:102:18: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'virtual size_t SoftwareSerial::write(uint8_t)'

   virtual size_t write(uint8_t byte);

                  ^~~~~

C:\Users\rafez\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\Hajji_Tracker\Hajji_Tracker.ino:144:33: warning: invalid conversion from 'String*' to 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' [-fpermissive]

     serialSIM808.write(longitude);   // Add value to url

                                 ^

In file included from C:\Users\rafez\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\Hajji_Tracker\Hajji_Tracker.ino:1:0:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SoftwareSerial\src/SoftwareSerial.h:102:18: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'virtual size_t SoftwareSerial::write(uint8_t)'

   virtual size_t write(uint8_t byte);

                  ^~~~~

C:\Users\rafez\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\Hajji_Tracker\Hajji_Tracker.ino: In function 'void loop()':

Hajji_Tracker:169:37: error: cannot convert 'char*' to 'String*' for argument '1' to 'void gsm_send_data(String*, String*)'

     gsm_send_data(latitude,longitude);

                                     ^

Multiple libraries were found for "SoftwareSerial.h"
 Used: C:\Program
exit status 1
invalid operands of types 'const char [12]' and 'char [16]' to binary 'operator+'
```

I have tried many things but can't get rid of these problems. How can I get my code to compile?

Here is my code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial serialSIM808(11, 10); //Arduino(RX=11), Arduino(TX=10) //you can replace these with any other pins
//Arduino(RX) to SIM808(TX)
//Arduino(TX) to SIM808(RX)
//Arduino(Gnd) to SIM808(Gnd)

  String data[5];
  #define DEBUG true
  String state,timegps;

  char latitude[16];// = "24";
  char longitude[16];// = "24";
  int numLatitude = 1,numLongitude = 100;



  void gsm_disConnect_gprs(){
  serialSIM808.write("AT+CGATT=0\r\n"); // Attach to GPRS
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println("GPRS off");
  }

void setup() {
  //Begin serial comunication with Arduino and Arduino IDE (Serial Monitor)
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial);

  //Being serial communication witj Arduino and SIM808
  serialSIM808.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.println("Setup Complete!");
  delay(200);

  sendData("AT+CGNSPWR=1",1000,DEBUG);//Turn on GPS(GNSS - Global Navigation Satellite System)
  delay(200);
  sendData("AT+CGNSSEQ=RMC",1000,DEBUG);//configure GPS sequence mode to RMC
  delay(200);
  sendData("AT+CGPSSTATUS?",1000,DEBUG);//check if GPS status is either 2D or 3D fix location. You can use this AT command to check te GPS status manually using the serial monitor.


  getGPSLocation();

  serialSIM808.write("AT+CREG?\r\n");
  delay(150);
  gsm_connect_gprs();

}

void getGPSLocation()
{
//--------------------- send SMS containing google map location---------------------
sendTabData("AT+CGNSINF",1000,DEBUG);//Get GPS info(location
if (state !=0) {
Serial.println("State  :"+state);
Serial.println("Time  :"+timegps);
Serial.println("Latitude  :"+latitude);
Serial.println("Longitude  :"+longitude);
} else {
Serial.println("GPS Initializing… Items to check: Power supply 12v 2A; Antenna must be facing the sky and/or near the window; Power switch must be turned on.");
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}


void sendTabData(String command , const int timeout , boolean debug){

serialSIM808.println(command);
long int time = millis();
int i = 0;

while((time+timeout) > millis()){
while(serialSIM808.available()){
char c = serialSIM808.read();
if (c != ',') {
data[i] +=c;
delay(100);
} else {
i++;
}
if (i == 5) {
delay(100);
goto exitL;
}
}
}exitL:
if (debug) {
state = data[1];
timegps = data[2];
latitude = data[3];
longitude =data[4];
memset(data,0,sizeof(data));
}
}


String sendData (String command , const int timeout ,boolean debug){
String response = "";
serialSIM808.println(command);
long int time = millis();
int i = 0;

while ( (time+timeout ) > millis()){
while (serialSIM808.available()){
char c = serialSIM808.read();
response +=c;
}
}
if (debug) {
Serial.print(response);
}
return response;
}


void gsm_connect_gprs(){
  serialSIM808.write("AT+CGATT=1\r\n"); // Attach to GPRS
  delay(2000);
  serialSIM808.write("AT+SAPBR=1,1\r\n"); // Open a GPRS context
  delay(2000);
  //serialSIM808.write("AT+SAPBER=2,1\r\n");  // To query the GPRS context
  //delay(2000);
  Serial.println("GPRS on");
}


void gsm_send_data(String * latitude,String * longitude)
{
    Serial.println("Sending data.");    
    serialSIM808.write("AT+HTTPINIT\r\n");  // Initialize HTTP
    //Serial.print("AT+HTTPINIT\r\n");
    delay(1000);
    serialSIM808.write("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://499b.000webhostapp.com/?latitude=3&longitude=16\"\r\n"); // Send PARA command
    //serialSIM808.write("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://shehanshaman.000webhostapp.com/?id=");
    //Serial.print("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://shehanshaman.000webhostapp.com/?id=");
    delay(50);
    serialSIM808.write(latitude);   // Add id to the url
    //Serial.print(latitude);
    delay(50);
    serialSIM808.write("&longitude="); 
    //Serial.print("&longitude=");
    delay(50);
    serialSIM808.write(longitude);   // Add value to url
    //Serial.print(longitude);
    delay(50);
    serialSIM808.write("\"\r\n");   // close url

    //Serial.print("\"\r\n");
    delay(2000);
    serialSIM808.write("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1\r\n");    // End the PARA
    //Serial.print("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1\r\n");
    delay(2000);
    serialSIM808.write("AT+HTTPACTION=0\r\n");
    //Serial.print("AT+HTTPACTION=0\r\n");
    delay(3000);    
    serialSIM808.write("AT+HTTPTERM\r\n");
    //Serial.print("AT+HTTPTERM\r\n");
    //Serial.println();
    delay(3000);    
    Serial.print("data sent complete : ");
}

void loop() {
  //Read SIM808 output (if available) and print it in Arduino IDE Serial Monitor
  if(numLatitude<5){
    itoa(numLatitude, latitude, 10);
    itoa(numLongitude,longitude, 10);
    gsm_send_data(latitude,longitude);
    Serial.print(numLatitude);
    Serial.print(" >> ");
    Serial.print(numLongitude);
    Serial.println();
    delay(2000);
    numLatitude++;
    numLongitude+=45;
    if(numLatitude==5) gsm_disConnect_gprs();
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you supposed to use a `+`, not a `,` (e.g. `Serial.println("Latitude  :"+latitude);`)?

Comment: Feedback: this question contained a lot of "please halp me", including in the title. Readers will generally find this irksome and manipulative. This may be why three people (not me) have downvoted. This phrase also contains an implication of "please do my work for me" because "I can't be bothered" or "I have given up", and it is not a wonder that people do not take kindly to that. Keeping a positive can-do attitude is important here.

Answer (score 1):

Note the difference between [String](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/) and [char arrays](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/).

The + operator is not defined for Strings and char arrays.

Use two String objects instead.